# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected shape=(None, 160, 160, 3), found shape=(32, 160, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build an image classifier using the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2.
Here is the code of the model:

```
    img_size = (160, 160)
    img_shape = img_size + (3,)
    print(img_shape)
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=img_shape,
                                                   include_top=False,
                                                   weights='imagenet')

    base_model.trainable = False
    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")

    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=img_size + (3,))
    print("shape",inputs.shape)
    x = preprocess_input(inputs)
    x = base_model(x, training=False)
    x = global_average_layer(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    outputs = prediction_layer(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

```
    base_learning_rate = 0.0001
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

But when I try to feed it data it outputs the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected shape=(None, 160, 160, 3), found shape=(32, 160, 3)
```

I don't understand why am I getting this error, I reshaped all the images and if I print their shape the output is:

```
(160, 160, 3)
```

The same shape the model is expecting. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: The model is expecting batch dimension. You need to batch your data if you are using tf.data

Answer (score 0):

Your model is expecting input of shape 4-D, but you are giving 3-D input.
Need to add extra batch dimension as mentioned in comment by @Frightera
.

```
image = (160, 160, 3)
tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0).shape.as_list()

output:
(1, 160, 160, 3)
```